# How do I run multiple ssh commands concurrently in a bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm using ROS on Linux and the usual workflow involves `ssh`ing into the machine, running the necessary command, and then starting a new terminal window, `ssh` again, etc. I would like to run a bash script for this but I'm a little stuck. I can't run these commands sequentially, I need to open up a new terminal so that they all run concurrently. How would I do this in a bash with ssh?

Comment: Are you talking about sshing into multiple machines simultaneously?

Comment: Or [ClusterSSH](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-multiple-linux-servers-clusterssh)

Comment: ssh also has a -f option to go into the background

Answer (score 1):

To run four commands concurrently:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
command4 &
```

`&` tells the shell to run the preceding command in the background, allowing the shell script to proceed to the next command without waiting for the previous one to finish.

If, by chance, you want to wait for all four commands to complete before doing some other task, use the `wait` command.  See `man bash` for more details.